# "Missing Package Product" error in Xcode when adding a new package

Tags: swift, xcode

After adding a package (Kingfisher) to my Xcode project, I noticed the following error when building:

[image]

I am not sure why I am getting this error, because from what I can tell the package was added correctly. I've verified that in the *Targets > Frameworks* section I see the package Kingfisher listed:

[image]

I've also verified that in the *Project > Package Dependencies* section, I see the package listed:

[image]

Furthermore, I even tried to just remove the dependency on this package altogether by removing it from both the *Targets > Frameworks* section using the "-" button, and I did so as well in the *Project > Package Dependencies* section. However even after removing it from both of these places I still get the same error when trying to build, which was very surprising.

I'm new to xcode so any help/tips would be appreciated

Comment: what is the output from running this command in terminal?    
  

`sw_vers ; echo ; xcodebuild -version ; echo ; swift package --version ; swift --version`

Answer (score 0):

The problem might as well be in some cached data that still dwell in `DerivedData`. Try deleting `DerivedData` for your project and then reinstantiate package again. Also clean build folder with `Cmd + Shift + K` You can open your `DerivedData` folder in finder window directly through `Xcode`  by navigating to: `Xcode -> Preferences -> Location` and clicking on the small arrow next to `DerivedData` directory.

Comment: Hmm. After I deleted all the derived data for the project, then removed and re-added all of the packages, now I get the same error as before but for every single package. The packages appear to have been added correctly, and I see they each have a directory in the build dir, so I'm not sure why they all show as missing now

Comment: did you found solution to your problem ?